# getAll() does not work in unit tests

Tags: grails, spock

For a simple domain class like this:

```
class Color {
    String name;
}
```

Why doesn't the `getAll()` work?

```
@TestFor(MyColorService)
@TestMixin(DomainClassUnitTestMixin)
@Mock([Color, Shade, ColorShade])
class MyColorServiceSpec extends Specification {
    def color

    def setup() {
        color = new Color(name: "red")
        color.save(flush: true)
    }

    def "test colors by shade" () {
        expect:
            1 == Color.count
            "red" == Color.all[0].name
            "red" == Color.getAll([1]).name
    }
}
```

The test fails with:

```
"red" == Color.getAll([1]).name
      |        |           |
      false    [null]      []
```

I've tried this on grails `2.2.4` and `2.4.0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
 "red" == Color.getAll([1L]).name
```

You are using an integer whilst the id type for domain classes is `Long`

Comment: that works. should i send pull request for this part of documentation to change? http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/getAll.html